# Zend Framework setting up the htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have been using the Zend Framework for years but have realised some crucial problems with our error handling that we are now fixing.
(I posted a different question here: [Why my site is always using the ErrorController for all types of errors irrespective of HTTP Status code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197946/why-my-site-is-always-using-the-errorcontroller-for-all-types-of-errors-irrespec) explaining the story there).

My question here is a quick one. What does a common .htaccess file of Zend Framework look like?

According to the [latest ZF documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html),

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

However, the above is new to me - can someone explain what it does exactly?
My current .htaccess file has a lot of 301 redirect code but for the purpose of this post I'll only paste the relevant information here:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/pagenotfound/
ErrorDocument 503 http://www.mydomain.com/service-unavailable/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/liveagent
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|png|PNG|pdf|css|html|xml|swf|php|mp3|mp4|webm|ogv|f4v|flv|txt|wsdl|css3|ttf|eot|svg|woff)$ index.php
```

The above has been working fine for us, and basically disallows the "liveagent" and "blog" (Wordpress) directories from running with Zend, but I realise I now need to make the following change:

ErrorDocument 404 definitely has to be removed from the code, as Zend Framework should handle all errors. However, when I remove this, going to a URL like www.mydomain.com/this-does-not-exist.php results in a 404 error standard Apache page - it does not load the ZF or the ErrorController. This is because of the "php" exclusion in the above RewriteRule. I do not simply want to remove this since we sometimes want to be able to access php files on the root, such as a separate "holding.php" file which we use for putting the site on maintenance mode.

What is the standard practice? Should I remove the php extension? However this will not solve other 404's like
www.mydomain.com/this-does-not-exist.css
which is also an exclusion (i.e. CSS) in the above RewriteRule.

Therefore, should I completely change the above to Zend's new code for .htaccess as I mentioned above?

If so, I'm a sort of beginner at htaccess - how can I modify that .htaccess code to allow CSS, JS, video files etc. and the blog and liveagent directories to be excluded from the Zend Framework?

Comment: Are you open for solution? Are you open to discussion? Do you even know there is "comments" section? With hardwork and patience I wrote the answer for your question in the link you provided, did you throw lights about it? Did you comment on my answer and asked the question properly? Do you even know what you are REALLY Looking for?

Comment: Firstly thanks very much for your thorough reply on the other post, I was meaning to send you a reply once I actually tried it, I apologise for any offense as I needed to go through it with another colleague. On a different note, I think, my .htaccess file was not addressed in the other post - in fact, it was causing an urgent problem (as explained above) which I now realise is a different problem to my previous post, one that I need to focus on before moving back to the ErrorController. Hence a new question, to ask what a standard htaccess looks like. Hope you understand, and thanks again.

Comment: sure, I understand... Take your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd switch to the standard ZF rewrite rules instead of the one you have which uses a long regex to redirect to index.php.

Here is an explanation of what the standard `.htaccess` rules do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] # The request is a regular file with size > 0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] # The request is to a file that is a symlink
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] # The request is to a directory that exists

# if any of the above conditions are true, then simply handle the request as-is
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# if none of the above match, then rewrite to index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

These default ZF rules don't prevent you from accessing existing `php` files or any other files that are accessible from your document root.  *If the file requested exists*, then the request for that file is served as is.  *If the file requested does not exist*, then the request is forwarded to index.php

Once the request is forwarded to ZF, if there is no matching route, then the ZF ErrorHandler is called and a 404 page (from ZF) is served.

Using the stock ZF rules won't prevent you from having the desired behavior in your application and server settings, and should be a bit more efficient that the regex you currently have.  The only things that will really change is that now requests for files that don't exist will be handled by ZF's error handler and no longer by Apache.

Hopefully that answered your question, if not feel free to comment for clarification.

Comment: Thanks so much for this and the whole explanation, this works great. Just a general question about .htaccess - the second RewriteRule above (# if none of the above match, then rewrite to index.php) - that one basically executes only if the above one fails? Basically the first RewriteRule executes if one of the conditions above are met. It then stops and .htaccess stops going forward with the other RewriteRules. ELSE if it doesn't execute, then the second RewriteRule is done. Is that correct?

Comment: `RewriteCond` are like if statements for rewrite rules.  So if any of the first 3 RewriteCond's are true, then the rule `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` is executed.  The `[L]` flag indicates "last" meaning that no more rules should be processed after that rule.  So if the file does exist based on one of the RewriteCond's, then the request is handled as is an the next rewrite rule for rewriting everything to index.php is never executed.  If none of the RewriteCond's are true, i.e. the file requested doesn't exist, then the second rewriterule for index.php is executed.  Hope that answered it.